# Выбрать студентов, которые проходили все указанные курсы

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с следующей задачей: необходимо выбрать всех студентов, которые прошли все указанные курсы. Свои догадки написал ниже, но данный запрос выбирает и тех студентов, которые прошли хотя бы один из указанных.

```
SELECT student.Id, student.FirstName, student.LastName, student.MiddleName FROM student 
INNER JOIN coursegroupe AS cg ON cg.IdCourse IN ( '045d4fdd-83ac-45d5-9c7b-cd8e9ce85bf6','e2b59d3c-9c1e-44f5-aa9c-190ce8f063b2')
INNER JOIN groupestudent AS gs ON gs.IdGroupe = cg.Id
WHERE student.Id = gs.IdStudent;
```

Comment: Думаю, ваш вопрос решат быстрее, если вы приведете в вопросе структуру своей базы и пару слов о каждой таблице

Answer (score 7):

Самое простое решение, которое пришло в голову - это оставить ваш запрос и наложить условие на группу

```
SELECT student.Id, student.FirstName, student.LastName, student.MiddleName FROM student 
INNER JOIN coursegroupe AS cg ON cg.IdCourse IN ( '045d4fdd-83ac-45d5-9c7b-cd8e9ce85bf6','e2b59d3c-9c1e-44f5-aa9c-190ce8f063b2')
INNER JOIN groupestudent AS gs ON gs.IdGroupe = cg.Id
WHERE student.Id = gs.IdStudent;
GROUP BY student.id
HAVING COUNT(cg.idCourse)=2
```

В целом смысл в том, что мы делаем JOIN и проверяем, что кол-во пройденных курсов из данных присоединенных данных два (HAVING COUNT(cg.idCourse)=2) естественно с использованием групировки (GROUP BY student.id)

Comment: coursegroupe нету поля студент, ссылка на студента содержится в groupestudent.

Comment: Да, извините, не заметил :) Структуру вашей базы данных не видел :)

Comment: Да, это Вы извините, что не скинул ее)