# sql поиск по нескольким строкам

Tags: mysql, sql

предположим,что у меня есть таблица со столбцами `product_id` и `category_id`, которая задает соответствие товара категории. у товара может быть несколько категорий.

пусть у меня есть массив `id`-шников категорий, например, такой - `[1,2,3]`.
вопрос - как мне с помощью `sql` запроса вывести `product_id` только тех товаров, которые принадлежат всем трем категориям?

т.е. например если для товара с `product_id` в таблице есть три строчки `1-1` `1-2` `1-3`, то мы выводим его.

Comment: `SELECT *  FROM table1 where product_id  in (1,2,3)` ?

Comment: @HELOWORD, нет, ваш запрос вернёт товары, у которых есть хотя бы одна категория. А нужно ВСЕ.

Comment: На примерно такой же вопрос отвечал здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553724/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b/553728#553728

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM YourTable U
WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: спасибо, кажется это то, что надо. а почему where условие вообще срабатывает? ведь мы же группируем, и там может быть несколько записей. я даже пробовал WHERE category_id = 1 (не IN), и это тоже возвращает результат

Comment: Там оператор IN(1, 2, 3) равносилен q=1 OR q=2 OR q=3